# When I clear option select onChange doesn't work again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this code:

```
success: function (data) {
                $('#' + idDivRefresh).endLoading();
                if (data.message != '@Geral.Sucesso') {
                    $('#' + idDropDown + 'option:selected').prop("selected", false)
                    $('#input-' + idDropDown).val('');
                    $('#' + idDropDown + 'option').each(function () {
                        if (this.defaultSelected) {
                            this.selected = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    alert(data.message);
                }
            }
```

I clear option selected on dropdown.
But when I select again another option, function for 'onChange' doesn't work.

HTML

```
<div id="iddb78e" class="field-Small">
    <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Ente must be a number." id="iddb78e" name="fornecedorVerbal.IdEnteIniciativaInvestment" style="display: none;">
    <option value=""> </option>
    <option value="4">30B66 - BUY CHANGES</option>
   </select>
    <input class="dropdown" type="text" id="input-iddb78e" autocomplete="off"></div>
```

Script OnChange

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $("#iddb78e select")
        .change(function () {
            Tst(53287)
        })
        .loadOptions('/Tst/Method/ListarJsonEnte?IdIniciativa=2105')
        .turnAutoComplete();
</script>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: please also show us a) the HTML of the dropdown, and b) the problematic onChange handler. Then we have a complete workable example of the issue

Comment: `idDropDown + 'option:selected'` needs a space separator: `idDropDown + ' option:selected'`, also further down your code.

Comment: Same in `$('#' + idDropDown + 'option')` should be `$('#' + idDropDown + ' option')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS selector that you build with the following expression:

```
'#' + idDropDown + 'option'
```

...will become...

```
'#iddb78eoption'
```

So jQuery will look for an element with the `id` *iddb78eoption* which it obviously does not find. So nothing happens as a result.

What you really want is a space (or greater-than sign) there:

```
'#iddb78e option'
```

So make sure to add that space like this:

```
'#' + idDropDown + ' option'
```

There are two places in your code where this needs to happen.